# Youtube video player customisation

Tags: ios, objective-c, youtube-api

Are there any API in google to get the url of the video content, so that i can play it in "MPMoviePlayerController" or is it possible to customise the player to such a extent that it does not resemble the youtube player. (like hiding "info bar" that appears once the movie completes, play button, activity indicator ...)

Comment: Currently, there is no documented way to do what you're hoping.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should have a look at this component:
https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeVideoPlayerViewController

Comment: Thanks, But once again we end up in parsing the data and the format of the data which we receive from the api in not documented by google, It may change in future, Please suggest a solution